# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, application

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to derive the function $$F(x)=\int_a^{x^2}\sin^3t\,dt$$ with the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I dont know how to handle the $x^2$.

Maybe with subsitution I think

Fundamental theorem of calculus: Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Then the function $$F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R},\; x\mapsto \int_a^xf(t)dt$$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $\frac{\partial F(x)}{dx}=f(x)$.

Could you help me to apply the theorem?

I only know how to do it without the theorem, if you use $$\sin^3(t)=\frac{d(\frac{1}{3}\cos^3t-\cos t))}{dt}$$

Comment: I believe you should read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Use the [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) $$f(g(x))' = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$$

where $$f(x) = \int_a^{x} \sin^3 t \,\,dt$$

and $g(x) = x^2.$

Comment: ok, thank you. How to do it exactly, $\int_a^{x^2}sin^3(t)dt=\int_a^{t}sin^3(x^2)2xdx$ is wrong I think?

Comment: @AaronMaroja You have a mistake in the upper limit of integration.

Comment: @JessicaK what mistake?

Comment: @Flap Think again. Take the derivative exactly as it is written on the chain rule.

Comment: oops. maybe $\int_a^{x^2}sin^3(t)dt=\int_a^{t}sin^2(x^2)*3*cos(x^2)2xdx$?

Comment: @AaronMaroja As defined, $f(g(x))^{\prime} = D\int_{a}^{x^{4}} \sin^{3}t\operatorname{d}t$.

Comment: @Flap There is no integral once you've taken the derivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: @JessicaK Thanks, corrected.

Comment: I really don't know how to do it

Comment: @Flap First $f'(x) = \sin^3 x$ and $g'(x) = 2x$. Also $f'(x^2) = \sin^3 (x^2)$. Then all in all we have $$h'(x) = 2x \dot\, \sin^3 (x^2)$$ where $h(x) = F(x)$.

Comment: ok, thanks, now I understand what you mean with "There is no integral once you've taken the derivative of $f(x)$  . Is then $\int_a^{x^2}sin^3(t)dt=\int_a^t 2xsin^2(x^2)dx$ correct?

Comment: @flap refresh this page.

Answer (score 3):

one form of the fundamental theorem of calculus is $$d\left(\int_a^b f(t) \, dt \right) = f(b)\, db - f(a) \, da \tag 1$$  if you keep the lower limit fixed at $a$ and the upper limit is a variable $x^2,$ then $(1)$ becomes 
$$d\left(\int_a^{x^2} \sin^3 t\, dt \right) = \sin^3\left(x^2\right)\, d\left(x^2\right) - \sin^3(a) \times 0 =  2x\sin^3\left(x^2\right)\, dx$$  now, dividing by $dx$  gives $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_a^{x^2} \sin^3 t\, dt \right) = 2x\sin^3\left(x^2\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

### $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_a^{x^2}\sin^3t\,dt$

Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \int_a^x\sin^3t\,dt$

Note that the variable $t$ is unimportant. It would mean exactly the same thing if we had said

Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \int_a^x\sin^3u\,du$
We know that $f'(x) = \sin^3x$
So $f'(x^2) = \sin^3(x^2)$.

Next, let $g(x) = x^2$.
We know that $g'(x) = 2x$.

Then $\displaystyle f(g(x)) = \int_a^{x^2}\sin^3t\,dt = F(x)$.

The chain rule tells us that

\begin{align}
  F'(x)
  &= f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \\
  &= f'(x^2) \cdot g'(x) \\
  &= \sin^3(x^2) \cdot(2x) \\
  &= 2x \sin^3(x^2)
\end{align}